# Add UITableView in Today extension

Tags: ios, today-extension

I am new in iOS.

I want to use Today extension. I have created Today extension and add uitableview it works fine. but when I try to select row then delegate Method **DidSelectRowAtIndexPath** doesn't call.

In my code there are 3 methods of uitableview delegate and datasources.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return 3;
}

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello World%li",(long)indexPath.row];
return cell;

}

   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
      return 1;
     }
```

Above Datasources Method call correctly

but didselect row method doesn't call after selection of row.

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
       NSLog(@"row Selected");
     }
```

appreciate for help.

Comment: were you able to scroll table view (only) ? if there is more data ?

Answer (score 1):

You mention that the data source methods are called. But `tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is a `UITableViewDelegate` method, not a data source method. It looks like the table view's `delegate` property might not be set.

Answer (score 0):

Implement UITableViewDelegate protocol in your table View class same as UITableViewDataSource is implemented. **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** will work fine i.e will be called when a row from table is selected.